# jquery - get the position number of clicked td in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>me</td>
      <td>you</td>
      <td>we</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Using Jquery i want to know which childrin was clicked and get the number of this childrin. like, if I click `you`, i want to get 2 and if `we`, then 3.. if `me`, then 1.

is there something like `.nthchild();` in Jquery?

here is my fiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/vfp9x/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use `$(this).index()`, **you also have wrong id** for `table` in live demo, it should be `table1`

Remember the index is zero based so you will get zero `0` for first element and 1 for second element and so on.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vfp9x/6/)**

```
$('#table1').on('click', 'td', function () {    
    $('#out').text($(this).index()+1);
});
```

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
$('#table1').on('click','td',function(){
    var child_number = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').index(this);
    $('#out').text(child_number);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vfp9x/8/)

---

Simply use `.index()` as per the other answer provider suggested, and also keep this way of getting the index also. it would helpful for you in some other contexts, like getting the index of the current element from a collection of elements (not siblings to each other)

Comment: hi , you should have given little solution and fiddle. Look Adil is getting more +1s .

Comment: Its ok :)  It happens , You will get more repo. than him one day .And by the way, u goto IT company ,then does ur Boss allow to use Stack Overflow for 5,6 hours ? :)  If yes ,u r lucky

Comment: @PratikJoshi currently working in a front-end app intensively, but in my comp i do both of the works asynchronously... :)

Comment: Then I will have to tell ur boss ,that if u tel Raja to work only on projects than STkOverflow,Ur company wil get twice benifit,and money.

Comment: please tell ur monthly income if u want to say.Please .u r great

Comment: @PratikJoshi That's secret.. `:)`

Comment: then Just  tell salary > 30k or less than that, dnt tell exact figure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56578/discussion-between-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy-and-pratik-joshi).

Answer (score 0):

Try Like

```
$("#ul").on('click', 'td', function () {
    debugger;
    alert(this.id);    
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/369qP/)

Comment: thanks, but i would have to give id to each td in a table with 190 tds.

Comment: @doniyor , if u r using PHP its Easy.

Comment: which coding language at Backend u use? Or nothing

Comment: @PratikJoshi django/python